# "Spell check" and return the corrected term in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spell-checking

I recently extracted text data from a directory of pdf files. When reading pdfs, sometimes the text returned is a little messy.

For example, I can be looking at a string that says:

> "T he administrati on is doing bad things, and not fulfilling what it
>   prom ised"

I want the result to be:

> "The administration is doing bad things, and not fulfilling what it
>   promised"

I tested code (using pyenchant and wx) I found on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026394/how-to-correct-text-and-return-the-corrected-text-automatically-with-pyenchant) and it did not return what I wanted. My modifications were as follows:

```
a = "T he administrati on is doing bad things, and not fulfilling what it prom ised"
chkr = enchant.checker.SpellChecker("en_US")
chkr.set_text(a)
for err in chkr:
    sug = err.suggest()[0]
    err.replace(sug)

c = chkr.get_text()#returns corrected text
print(c)
```

This code returns:

> "T he administrate on is doing bad things, and not fulfilling what it
>   prom side"

I'm using Python 3.5.x on a Windows 7 Enterprise, 64-bit. I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have taken [Generic Human’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11642687/8709791), slightly modified it to solve your problem.

You need to copy these [125k words, sorted by frequency](http://pasted.co/c1666a6b) into a text file, name the file `words-by-frequency.txt`.

```
from math import log

# Build a cost dictionary, assuming Zipf's law and cost = -math.log(probability).
with open("words-by-frequency.txt") as f:
    words = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    wordcost = dict((k, log((i+1)*log(len(words)))) for i,k in enumerate(words))
    maxword = max(len(x) for x in words)

def infer_spaces(s):
    """Uses dynamic programming to infer the location of spaces in a string
    without spaces."""

    # Find the best match for the i first characters, assuming cost has
    # been built for the i-1 first characters.
    # Returns a pair (match_cost, match_length).
    def best_match(i):
        candidates = enumerate(reversed(cost[max(0, i-maxword):i]))
        return min((c + wordcost.get(s[i-k-1:i], 9e999), k+1) for k,c in candidates)

    # Build the cost array.
    cost = [0]
    for i in range(1,len(s)+1):
        c,k = best_match(i)
        cost.append(c)

    # Backtrack to recover the minimal-cost string.
    out = []
    i = len(s)
    while i>0:
        c,k = best_match(i)
        assert c == cost[i]
        out.append(s[i-k:i])
        i -= k

    return " ".join(reversed(out))
```

Running the function with the input:

```
messy_txt = "T he administrati on is doing bad things, and not fulfilling what it prom ised"

print(infer_spaces(messy_txt.lower().replace(' ', '').replace(',', '')).capitalize())


The administration is doing bad things and not fulfilling what it promised
>>>
```

**Edit**: The code below doesn't require the text file and works *just* for your input i.e., "T he administrati on is doing bad things, and not fulfilling what it prom ised"

```
from math import log

# Build a cost dictionary, assuming Zipf's law and cost = -math.log(probability).
words = ["the", "administration", "is", "doing", "bad",
         "things", "and", "not", "fulfilling", "what",
         "it", "promised"]
wordcost = dict((k, log((i+1)*log(len(words)))) for i,k in enumerate(words))
maxword = max(len(x) for x in words)

def infer_spaces(s):
    """Uses dynamic programming to infer the location of spaces in a string
    without spaces."""

    # Find the best match for the i first characters, assuming cost has
    # been built for the i-1 first characters.
    # Returns a pair (match_cost, match_length).
    def best_match(i):
        candidates = enumerate(reversed(cost[max(0, i-maxword):i]))
        return min((c + wordcost.get(s[i-k-1:i], 9e999), k+1) for k,c in candidates)

    # Build the cost array.
    cost = [0]
    for i in range(1,len(s)+1):
        c,k = best_match(i)
        cost.append(c)

    # Backtrack to recover the minimal-cost string.
    out = []
    i = len(s)
    while i>0:
        c,k = best_match(i)
        assert c == cost[i]
        out.append(s[i-k:i])
        i -= k

    return " ".join(reversed(out))


messy_txt = "T he administrati on is doing bad things, and not fulfilling what it prom ised"

print(infer_spaces(messy_txt.lower().replace(' ', '').replace(',', '')).capitalize())

The administration is doing bad things and not fulfilling what it promised
>>>
```

I have just tried the above edit at [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/TurquoiseBewitchedAfricanaugurbuzzard) and it printed the output as shown.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and the output doesn't match what your output is: T h e a d m i n i s t r a t i o n i s d o i n g b a d t h i n g s , a n d n o t f u l f i l l i n g w h a t i t p r o m i s e d

Comment: Have you copied the text file?

Comment: If you have not yet,  copy these [125k words, sorted by frequency](http://pasted.co/c1666a6b) into a text file and put the file in the same folder as your Python file.

Comment: You can also download the text file from [My Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CrmgxQKzlgEhnu94276S55kvfwl0yAxh/view). My output is still the same: `The administration is doing bad things and not fulfilling what it promised`

Comment: Yes I downloaded the text file and checked the block of  code that runs it- and it is reading in the file correctly. Unfortunately my output still looks strange like I noted above 

Comment: Please see the edit, which hopefully shows that the original code works for inputs similar to yours.

Comment: Please see the edit work at [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/TurquoiseBewitchedAfricanaugurbuzzard).

Comment: Thanks! The code works now! I did notice one thing, if you remove the second .replace(',', '') in your print statement it causes the weird spacing. Do you know why that might be?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the enchant library you're using just isn't that good. It doesn't look for spelling mistakes across words, but instead just looks at words individually. I guess this makes sense since the function itself is called 'SpellChecker'.

The only thing I can think of is to look for better autocorrect libraries.
Maybe this one might help? 
https://github.com/phatpiglet/autocorrect

No guarantees though.