# Autocorrect a column in a pandas dataframe using pyenchant

Tags: pandas, pyenchant

I tried to apply the code from the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026394/how-to-correct-text-and-return-the-corrected-text-automatically-with-pyenchant) to one of my dataframe columns where each row is a sentence, but it didn't work.

My code looks this:

```
from enchant.checker import SpellChecker
checker = SpellChecker("id_ID")

h = df['Jawaban'].astype(str).str.lower()
hayo = []


for text in h:
    checker.set_text(text)

    for s in checker:
        sug = s.suggest()[0]
        s.replace(sug)

    hayo.append(checker.get_text())
```

I got this following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: checker is the alias name of pyenchant ?

Comment: Yes! Just edited my code to include the import statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get the error using your code. The only thing I'm doing differently is to import the spell checker.

```
from enchant.checker import SpellChecker
checker = SpellChecker('en_US','en_UK') # not using id_ID

# sample data
ds = pd.DataFrame({ 'text': ['here is a spllng mstke','the wrld is grwng']})
p = ds['text'].str.lower()

hayo = []

for text in p:
    checker.set_text(text)

    for s in checker:
        sug = s.suggest()[0]
        s.replace(sug)

    print(checker.get_text())
    hayo.append(checker.get_text())

print(hayo)

here is a spelling mistake
the world is growing
```

Comment: Now that's incredibly weird...... My error is at the s.suggest()[0] part. Anothe weird thing is, if I don't try to append and simply print the whole thing, I won't get the error

Comment: i just tried it and it worked. i don't know what's wrong but if i don't print the result it will throw me an error so i guess the way to do it to always print in the end. thank you btw!